# MVC JQuery Load Partial With Image potentially dangerous Request

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I want to load a Partial View through jQuery and load it into the page.  The Partial View has an `<img>` in it.

Here is the PartialView:

```
@model NBAPicks.Models.PickedTeamLogoViewModel

@ViewHelpers.GetTeamLogoForPick(Model.TeamAbbr, Model.GameID, Model.UserName)
```

And here is the helper code:

```
public static MvcHtmlString GetTeamLogoForPick(string abbr, int gameID, string userName)
{
    var imagePath = ImageUrl("Team Logos", abbr + ".gif");
    var html = "<img src=\"" + imagePath + "\" id=\"" + gameID.ToString() + "_" + userName + "\" class=\"pick-logo\" />";
    return new MvcHtmlString(html);
}
```

Where the ImageUrl is:

```
private static string ImageUrl(string subFolder, string fileName)
{
    return VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(ImagesDir + "\\" + subFolder + "\\" + fileName);
}
```

Here is the Controller method:

```
[Authorize]
public JsonResult GetPickedTeamLogo(string teamAbbr, int gameID, string userName)
{
    var viewModel = new PickedTeamLogoViewModel()
    {
        TeamAbbr = teamAbbr,
        GameID = gameID,
        UserName = userName
    };
    return Json(_partialStringRenderer.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "_PickedTeamLogo", viewModel), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And here is where I load it in jQuery:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Html.Raw(Url.Content("~/Admin/GetPickedTeamLogo/?teamAbbr="))' + teamAbbr + '&gameID=' + gameID + '&userName=' + userName,
        cache: false,
        data: { teamAbbr: teamAbbr, gameID: gameID, userName: userName },
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function () {
            console.log('failure');
            alert('AJAX fail - this is a bug, report it!');
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log('AJAX call returned successfully');
            console.log('result: ' + result);
            $("#" + userName + "_logo").load(result); // HERE!!!
        }
    });
}, 0);
```

Now, through the console output the html returned looks fine and correct:

```
<img src="/Content/Team Logos/MIA.gif" id="1238_tim" class="pick-logo" />
```

But the console reports this error where I try and load the html:

> GET http://localhost:53441/%3Cimg 400 (Bad Request)

I can drill down from here into this error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).

Why is this error occurring, and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the request field contain a `<`, triggering ASP MVC safeguard, thinking a user might try to submit a script tag or whatever.

To solve this, add this action filter to your GetPickedTeamLogo controller action :

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

Edit : 
Sorry, i forgot, you also have to add this in your  in your web.config

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

Edit2 :

Ok, your problem come from the fact that your helper return you a img tag that you try to use as a url (result) in the `$("#" + userName + "_logo").load(result);`

You don't neet to call load but just append your image like this :

```
$("#" + userName + "_logo").append(result);
```

Comment: Ah, same result unfortunately.

Comment: Does it output strictly the same error after you added the filter to the GetPickedTeamLogo action ?

Comment: I had forgotten a mandatory web.config tag for this to work, see my edit above

Comment: I added that in my system.web section of the web.config.  It has the same result!

Comment: A question that comes to mind, why do you have a < in a parameter ?

Comment: This I do not know - where is it, can you see it?

Comment: In your browser dev tools (F12) you should have a network monitor where you can see all request sent by you page, and so, their url.

Comment: I am unable to see it.  I have on which is just %3Cimg, seems to be the same as the one in my question above where I cite the console (F12) error.  This same html comes out in my page on the load where similar images with the same helper code come out.  The console for them looks right - e.g. MIA.gif.  I am unsure why this request is %3Cimg, and why it is causing this error.

Comment: Thank you, sir.  An excellent solution that has done the job.  I did not need the validation stuff at the top, just the solution in Edit 2.  Thank you very much.